# Remove line from notepad++ (regex)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have lines like this:

```
whatisthis||
whatisth|searchfor
whatisth||
whatist|searchfor
what|
what||
```

I want automatically remove these one:

```
whatis||
```

And

```
what|
```

With regex on notepad++, how can i do please ?
All wanted line are those have two parameters:

```
whatist|searchfor
```

I want only the line like this:

```
EXAMPLE|EXAMPLE
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you show us what you have tried...

Comment: I tried this: `.*.||*\r\n` and `.*.|*\r\n` But no success

Comment: resolved with this: `^(.*)\|$` thank you

Comment: What is the difference between `what||` and `whatisthis||`? Why only `what||` should be removed?

Comment: No , all line finish by || will be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the end of line anchor `$`

```
search:  .*\|(\r?\n|$)
replace: nothing
```

or better:

```
search:  (\r?\n|^).*\|$
replace: nothing
```

Comment: @user3587044: Yes, but my pattern removes the newline.